# Trash Folders In ZFS Snapshots Recognized As Official Trash

Tags: zfs, trash, gvfs, snapshot

When I run `gvfs-ls trash://` or go to Trash in `nautilus`, I see the trash from my ZFS snapshots. This should not be happening. I'm sure this is impacting performance issues I have been seeing lately.

Can someone out there with snapshots containing `.Trash-1000` folders check if they are showing up on your systems?

Is there a way to configure the trash backend (`gvfs?`) to ignore `.zfs` folders?

Comment: OP - I just restarted my ubuntu because gvfs-trash process was killing my system. After reboot, recycle bin is now showing as empty. I'm going to keep an eye on this....

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be a bug with Gnome and related to the `.Trash-1000` directories in extra zfs datasets.

I have posted a bug with Gnome: [Trash Folders In ZFS Snapshots Show Up In gvfs-ls Output](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/622#note_1439367)

The only way to avoid this is to not do file system scan of any kind against multiple snapshot directories, that contain `.Trash-1000`, in a short period of time. Otherwise, you system may hang and become unusable.